# i have a error of firebase_core_web , did ant one have the same

Tags: android, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication, yaml

Error: Assertion failed: file:///C:/Users/ayknes/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/firebase_core_web-2.3.0/lib/src/firebase_core_web.dart:256:11
C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/*internal/js_dev_runtime/private/ddc_runtime/errors.dart 266:49  throw*
C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/private/ddc_runtime/errors.dart 29:3    assertFailed
packages/firebase_core_web/src/firebase_core_web.dart 256:18                                                               initializeApp
C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/patch/async_patch.dart 45:50            
C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/async/zone.dart 1660:54                                          runUnary
C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/async/future_impl.dart 147:18                                    handleValue
C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/async/future_impl.dart 767:44                                    handleValueCallback

Application finished.

to run my application with firebase

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.